# MaterialBottomTabNavigator / React-Native / React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

im using the Material-Bottom-Tab-Navigatior and would like to get a transparent bar background however my result atm looks like this
[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQXcN.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

import HomePage from '../components/whatsOn/HomePage';
import ComingSoon from '../components/comingSoon/ComingSoon';
import Favourites from '../components/favourites/Favourites';

import config from '../static/config.json';
import texts from '../static/texts.json';

const { gradient } = config.colors;
const { ComingSoonTitle, HomeTitle, FavouritesTitle } = texts.Tabs;
const lang = config.language;

export const TabStack = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
  comingSoon: {
    screen: ComingSoon,
    activeTintColor: gradient.primary,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarColor: 'transparent',
      tabBarLabel: ComingSoonTitle[lang],
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="calendar" color={tintColor} size={24} />),
    },
  },
  whatsOn: {
    screen: HomePage,
    activeTintColor: gradient.primary,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarColor: 'transparent',
      tabBarLabel: HomeTitle[lang],
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="film" color={tintColor} size={24} />),
    },
  },
  favourites: {
    screen: Favourites,
    activeTintColor: gradient.primary,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarColor: 'transparent',
      tabBarLabel: FavouritesTitle[lang],
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="star" color={tintColor} size={24} />),
    },
  },
}, {
  shifting: true,
  initialRouteName: 'whatsOn',
  order: ['comingSoon', 'whatsOn', 'favourites'],
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
});
```

this TabStack is nested inside this stack:

```
export const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Tabs: {
    screen: TabStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Compeso',
      header: props => <CustomHeader {...props} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: '500',
        color: colors.typography,
      },
      headerRight: MenuIcon,
      headerLeft: SearchIcon,
      animationEnabled: true,
    },
  },
  Drawer: {
    screen: MoreInfromation,
  },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Tabs',
  cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
});
```

the HomeStack is nested in a switchNavigator

```
export default class Router extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <MainStack />
    );
  }
}

const MainStack = createSwitchNavigator({
  Auth: LoginStack,
  Home: HomeStack,
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});
```

This MainStack is getting rendered in my App.js

I put this tab navigator into a stack navigator and each component that gets displayed shows a scroll view with a height of 815 pixels to make sure the background is behind the bar.

Can someone advice ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `barStyle`.
So, for transparent the style will be something like this:

```
barStyle: {backgroundColor:'transparent'}
```

In your code it will look something like this(included at bottom).

```
export const TabStack = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
  comingSoon: {
    ...
  },
  ...
}, {
  shifting: true,
  initialRouteName: 'whatsOn',
  order: ['comingSoon', 'whatsOn', 'favourites'],
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  barStyle: {backgroundColor:'transparent'}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately it's still the same

Comment: Which component did you set to black? I believe another component or `root` component is grey. Otherwise this should be transparent. I tested it, and it worked for me.

Comment: Do you know what happens if I change the stylesheet in node_modules/react-native-material-bottom-tabs/views/BottomTabBar.js ?

Comment: const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabBar: {
    backgroundColor: '#F7F7F7', // Default background color in iOS 10
    borderTopWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderTopColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },

Comment: That's not advisable, anytime you update `react-navigation` it will reset anyway. Also if you transfer your project, you wont include `node-modules` you have them in `package.json` then you `yarn install`. Which means you wont have the custom style.

Comment: Where is that style implemented? in `App.js`?

Comment: the tabs stack ist nested inside a createStackNavigator

Comment: No, where did you make the background color black?, please update your question above to include other code.

Comment: export const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Tabs: {
    screen: TabStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: props => <CustomHeader {...props} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontSize: 24,
        color: colors.typography,
      },
      headerRight: MenuIcon,
      headerLeft: SearchIcon,
      animationEnabled: true,
    },
  },
  Drawer: {
    screen: MoreInfromation,
  },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Tabs',
  cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
});

Comment: this is where im using the TabStack

Comment: class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default App;

Comment: this is my app.js

Comment: render() {
    return (
      <SideMenu
        openMenuOffset={window.width}
        menuPosition="right"
        menu={<Menu />}
        isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
        onChange={isOpen => this.updateMenuState(isOpen)}
      >
        <MainStack style={{ backgroundColor: colors.background }}/>
      </SideMenu>
    );
  }
}

const MainStack = createSwitchNavigator({
  Auth: LoginStack,
  Home: HomeStack,
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Auth',
});

Comment: this is the router file

Comment: I've edited the description so you can see it properly

Comment: try this `<View style={{backgroundColor:'orange'}}><MainStack  /></View>`, if the bar becomes orange than its transparent. in your `Router ` component

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I didn't get the result I wanted but I got the tab bar transparent.

Comment: the way you described

Comment: What do you mean? You changed the style in `Router`? That was for testing purposes. If you got it transparent, it means you can achieve what you wanted.